Virtual machine in windows server failover cluster can't access VLAN
I have made sure the physical switch ports can access the vlan I want. We have a failover cluster with two cluster nodes. We have about 8 VMs (roles) running just fine all on the same network (VLAN 1 - 10.10.3.0/16). We are trying to add a new VM to the cluster but want this VM to connect to a different VLAN (VLAN 16 - 10.16.1.0/24) than the other VMs. We can't get the new VM to see VLAN 16. The VM is running Windows 11 Pro and is a brand new VM. Cluster is on Windows Server 2022 Standard. We've tried a variety of network settings on the VM, the VM config, and the virtual switch, but can't get it configured properly. We just need some help with something I am possibly missing in the network configuration of the failover cluster. Everything else on the cluster has been running fine for years. Is it something I am missing on the virtual switch to have it access VLAN 16?
I did check the box in VM settings and set the VM to use VLAN16 here:
VLAN Setting
Thanks for any help!

It looks like you've done a solid job ensuring that the physical switch ports can access VLAN 16!
Here's some additional steps you might consider to troubleshoot the issue:
Virtual switch configuration: Make sure that the virtual switch in Hyper-V is set up to allow traffic for VLAN 16. You can do this by going into the virtual switch properties and confirming that VLAN 16 is configured correctly.
Virtual machine configuration: Check that the virtual machine’s network settings are assigned to VLAN 16. This can be done in the virtual network adapter properties, where you can specify the VLAN ID.
Network adapter configuration: Ensure that the virtual machine’s network adapter is set to tag traffic for VLAN 16. This might require installing specific drivers or adjusting advanced options in the network adapter.
Cluster validation: Run a cluster validation to make sure there are no underlying issues with the failover cluster setup. This can help identify any configuration problems that could be affecting VLAN connectivity.
Check event logs: Review the event logs in the Failover Cluster Manager to see if there are any errors or warnings related to network or VLAN configuration.
